# Expand Kendo PanelBar panel in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, expand

I'm trying to have the  first panel of my Kendo UI PanelBar grid be expanded when they page initially loads based on a parameter from a database. So instead of using class="k-state-active" on the li tag,  programmatically expanding the panel in the panelbar from my AngularJS controller.

Here is my Panel html:

```
  <ul kendo-panel-bar k-options="panelBarOptions" ng-controller="CreateItemCtrl" id="commentsPanelBar">
    <li style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;">
      COMMENTS
      <ul>
        <li style="height:140px;" id="pbComments">
           <input type='text' id='tbComments'></input>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Here is what I've tried in my controller code:

```
$scope.commentsPanelBar = {};
$scope.commentsPanelBar = $('#commentsPanelBar');
$scope.commentsPanelBar.data('kendoPanelBar').expand($('#pbComments'));
```

After running this code I just get an error that "expand" is not a function. I know the kendo scripts are referenced in this page because the PanelBar expands and collapses.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to reference the component by "commentsPanelBar" name. I think it's incorrect - as far as I know you should define the name you want to have in scope:

```
<ul kendo-panel-bar="kendoBar" ...>
```

You can reference the variable then by the name:

```
$scope.kendoBar.expand()
```

You can read about possible ways to define widget reference in Angular here:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#widget-references

Comment: I'm referencing it that way because my tag was like <ul kendo-panel-bar="commentsPanelBar" ...> . I have tried this method and it doesn't work either. Thanks for your reply however.